# Windows Phone 8 navigation issue between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation

I have a windows phone app with a login process, that login process accesses an external API.
The controller for the login button originally ran some code that instantly navigated to the dashboard page:

```
    private void LogInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Interface.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

This works fine!

Later on, I thought it best to implement the actual connection to the api, check if the user details are correct and on that, redirect to the dashboard. for brevity I have taken out the api parts, but let's say this function gets passed all over the place as an **Action delegate** before being called in it's rightful place, the controller..

```
    ...
    // This method is also located in the controller class, but it is called by another class
    public void LoadDashboard( DataUpdateState data )
    {
        //data.AsyncResponse
        App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Interface.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

The thing is, the navigation method now no longer works, it fires a debug break on RootFrame_NavigationFailed.

what am I not understanding here?

Is there a way of finding out just why it loaded the navigation failed method in the App class

Answer (score 2):

You can get more detail in the NavigationFailedEventArgs of the navigation failed event (in the Exception parameter).

The most probable cause is that you are try to call Navigate from a non ui thread. If that the case just use a dispatcher to dispatch it on the ui thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
        App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Interface.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

            });
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks. So basically, you can't just say... change page, you have to make sure that a new thread is ready and geared to do something for you?

Comment: no you just have to make sure that you are calling from the ui thread and not from a backgroud thread (it's exactly like you cannot change any ui component property from a background thread)

Comment: the only thing that Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke do is send the request back to the ui thread not starting anything

Comment: What probably happened insyou used a HttpWebRequest and the callback of a HttpWebRequest is on another thread (it's done so that you don't block the ui and the ui stay responsive)

Comment: nice one, makes sense