# windows phone 8 navigation error :app.rootframe_navigation failed

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation

I am creating an windows phone 8 app.In my app I have couple of pages and I want to navigate between pages.I create 8 page then i just try to navigate one page to another using this code

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/tespih3;content/tespih.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

from microsoft web page but I get error says: **`app.rootframe_navigation failed`**.

I also try to do this with `navigateuri hyperlinkbutton` properties but same error(it gets in debugger and says  *`A navigation has failed; break into the debugger`*) again.

What may cause this problem ?

Comment: Are you able to Navigate to any of your Pages? If it is only single case then try to [follow this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18883600/2681948).

Comment: this error come up when it is not able to find  the destination page. please check if your file names are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating to a page in the same assembly:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Folder(s)/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.relative));
```

Navigating to a page in another assembly:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/Folder(s)/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I try also this and same error NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.relative));

Comment: Use the first option if you dont have more than one assembly. The url you used in the question above is to be used only if it is in a different assembly.

Comment: What's the error you face? Can you provide deeper trace?

Comment: app.xaml.cs page is pop up in the screen and it shows this line of code  : private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                    Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: okey i solve my problem what was the mistake i dont know but i did same things and it works ty for feed backs